# Adding chromedriver to correct $PATH

Tags: ruby, path, rvm, filepath, selenium-chromedriver

When I type echo $PATH I get:

`/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/Users/myname/.rvm/bin:/Users/myname/.rbenv/shims:/Users/myname/.rbenv/shims:/Users/myname/.rbenv/shims:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`

And when I try to use chromedriver I get:

`/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.49.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:38:in 'executable_path': Unable to find the chromedriver executable. Please download the server from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and place it somewhere on your PATH.`

(I've downloaded chromedriver already).

Where would I place my chromedriver.exec file? And how would I do that?
I use RVM so that might be why there is no chromedriver in the correct path...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an RVM user, so I can't speak to its specifics, but in general you save the chromedriver executable somewhere on your filesystem. Then you need to add the file path to that location to your PATH variable. On a UNIX based system you can modify the PATH variable in your shell configuration file. For instance, with the bash shell you might have things set up in your .profile or .bashrc, etc. - just whatever you happen to be using in your set up. If you're not familiar with editing your PATH variable you might start here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

Comment: thank you for your response, i will look into this soon.